# Como guardar una variable en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito guardar una variable numérica,que genera números aleatorios pero siempre que trato de guardarla en mi base de datos me sale "Undefined variable"

Código que genera los números aleatorios:

```
        <?php 
            $num_lower = 1000;
            $num_hight = 9999;
            $num_solicitud = mt_rand($num_lower, $num_hight);
            echo $num_solicitud;
        ?>
```

Código con el que estoy tratando de guardar en mi base de datos:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$num_solicitud;
$name = $_POST['name_M'];
$notas = $_POST['notes'];    

$insertar = $conexion->query("INSERT INTO  solicitudes (name, num_solicitud, notas) VALUES ('$name', '$num_solicitud', '$notas')");

if ($insertar) {
    echo "<script>alert('Solicitud registrada exitosamente')</script>";
} else{
    echo '<script>("Ups...Algo No va bien")</script>';
}

}
```

?>

Esto es lo que tengo antes html:

```
<?php

 include 'config.php';

 session_start();



  if (!isset($_SESSION['nuip'])) {
    header("Location: pagina_principal.php");
  }


  ini_set('display_errors', '1');


  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  $num_solicitud = $_POST['num_solicitud'];
  $notas = $_POST['notes'];    

  $insertar = $conexion->query("INSERT INTO  examenes 
  (num_solicitud, notas) VALUES ('$num_solicitud', '$notas')");

  if ($insertar) {
    echo "<script>alert('Examen registrado exitosamente') 
  </script>";
   } else{
     echo '<script>("Ups...Algo No va bien")</script>';
   }

  }
```

?>

Mi código html:

```html
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <form method="post"><div class="titulo">
            <h1 class="tituloPrincipal">Bioreferencia</h1>
            <h6 class="parrafo_num_orden">Solicitud número: <?php 
                $num_lower = 1000;
                $num_hight = 9999;
                $num_solicitud = mt_rand($num_lower, $num_hight);
            ?><input type="hidden" name="num_solicitud" value="<?php echo $num_solicitud; ?>"></h6>
        </div></form>
```

Antes de iniciar el HTML tengo el codigo PHP donde estoy iniciando una sesión y también donde guardo todo lo enviado por el formulario a mi base de datos.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134781/discussion-on-question-by-juan-manuel-como-guardar-una-variable-en-mysql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que por un lado estas definiendo el $num_solicitud mientras estas mostrando tu HTML, pero cuando rellenan el formulario no lo estas enviando con los otros datos POST, y por lo tanto no puedes acceder a el.

La solución es dejar el código tal como lo tenias al principio de tu pregunta, pero realizando los siguientes cambios:

1. Modifica esto:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$num_solicitud;
```

por esto:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$num_solicitud = $_POST['num_solicitud];
```

2. Modifica esto:

```
<form method="post"><div class="titulo">
            <h1 class="tituloPrincipal">Bioreferencia</h1>
            <h6 class="parrafo_num_orden">Solicitud número: <?php 
                $num_lower = 1000;
                $num_hight = 9999;
                $num_solicitud = mt_rand($num_lower, $num_hight);
            ?><input type="hidden" name="num_solicitud" value="<?php echo $num_solicitud; ?>"></h6>
        </div></form>
```

y déjalo así:

```
<div class="titulo">
            <h1 class="tituloPrincipal">Bioreferencia</h1>
            <h6 class="parrafo_num_orden">Solicitud número: <?php 
                $num_lower = 1000;
                $num_hight = 9999;
                $num_solicitud = mt_rand($num_lower, $num_hight);
                echo $num_solicitud;
            ?></h6>
        </div>
```

pues ese `<form></form>` aquí no tiene ningun sentido, sobraba, y el campo input que te he pedido no era en este formulario, sino en el siguiente.

3. Ves a tu "otro" formulario HTML y modifica esto:

```
<form method="POST" class="formulario-datos">
<?php
```

por esto:

```
<form method="POST" class="formulario-datos">
<input type="hidden" name="num_solicitud" value="<?php echo $num_solicitud; ?>">
<?php
```

Con esto estarás agregando un campo oculto (hidden) con el valor de la variable `$num_solicitud` y con el nombre **num_solicitud** que en el paso 1 recuperaremos para poderlo usar en la consulta.

Prueba y me cuentas.

---

### Anterior respuesta (OBSOLETA: cuando no tenia todos los datos)

No se entiende demasiado bien lo que haces con $num_solicitud. Supongo que para arreglarlo debes ponerlo todo en el mismo script pues no se si lo haces en dos ahora mismo.

Es decir, la solución pasaria a ser esta:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $num_lower = 1000;
    $num_hight = 9999;
    $num_solicitud = mt_rand($num_lower, $num_hight);
    $name = $_POST['name_M'];
    $notas = $_POST['notes'];    

    $insertar = $conexion->query("INSERT INTO  solicitudes (name, num_solicitud, notas) VALUES ('$name', '$num_solicitud', '$notas')");

    if ($insertar) {
        echo "<script>alert('Solicitud registrada exitosamente')</script>";
    } else{
        echo '<script>("Ups...Algo No va bien")</script>';
    }
}
```